# xpages use image button go to each tab panel [Error]

Tags: xpages

I try using image button to direct update the tab panel, Every time i click on the button it give an error message.

[image: Tab Panel]
[image: Error]

Comment: Please, share the code you use in the event at least

Comment: dint use any code ...just use onclick event, and select the tab panel to refresh it. It is cannot direct partially refresh the tab panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to manually navigate to a given `tabPanel` you must invoke the `tabbedPanel` method to switch tab. For brevity's sake I post an example based on what you can do on the page itself without the proper intervention of a backing Java class:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <xp:link id="link1" text="select 1">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tabbedPanel1"
        action="#{javascript: tabbedPanel.setSelectedTab('tabPanel1')}">
      </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <xp:link id="link2" text="select 2">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tabbedPanel1"
        action="#{javascript: tabbedPanel.setSelectedTab('tabPanel2')}">
      </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:link>
  </li>
</ul>

<xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel1" binding="#{tabbedPanel}">
  <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab" id="tabPanel1">panel1</xp:tabPanel>
  <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab2" id="tabPanel2">panel2
  </xp:tabPanel>
</xp:tabbedPanel>
```

To invoke the tab change I grab hold of the tabbedPanel object. I create a handy handle by means of the binding property - `binding="#{tabbedPanel}"`. At this point the `tabbedPanel` can be accessed from anywhere in the page.

I wrote a couple of links whose `action` parameter implements `tabbedPanel.setSelectedTab('tabPanel1')}`. The `setSelectedTab` parameter value corresponds to the `tabPanel` id. The refresh, this is important, is then performed on the `tabbedPanel` - `tabbedPanel1` - and not the specific opened `tabPanel`.